# this list comprehension is showing error don't know how to fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to populate a list with boolean values I have a list for comparision, if the condition satisfies then True if not then False must be added to the list
I have tried something like

```
t_or_f = [True for car in car_types if car in new_car else False]
```

and

```
t_or_f = [True for car in car_types if car in new_car True else False]
```

I know that i can achieve it like this

```
for car in car_types:
    t_or_f.append(car in new_car)
```

where new_car and car_types are lists ,
but i need to know how i can minimise my code in this  situation using list comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
t_or_f = [car in new_car for car in car_types]
```

car in new_car will return True or False anyway so no need to make it more complicated

Comment: No worries, make sure to mark as the correct answer if this has solved your problem

Comment: Your method is correct though if i really get stuck in a situation where i needed to use if else then how can i use list comprehension with if/else inside forloop

Comment: [True if car in new_car else False for car in car_types ] would be the way to do this

Comment: once again Thanks @Anis Now i have the  **power of comprehension**